# response redirect from one page to another in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i have 2 pages, the first page user have to select radiobuttonlist , select 2 calendar date and fill the textbox. thus the 2nd page have to display all of it, but theres no fetch. when i run the program, there are no errors.

these are from the first page back code.

```
protected void lbnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateEmail();
    ValidateDate();

    if (lwarndate.Visible == false &&
        lwarnemail.Visible == false)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Staff/ApplyLeaveConfirm.aspx?qsLeaveCode=" + rblleavetype.SelectedValue.ToString() +
                          "&qsLeaveType=" + rblleavetype.SelectedItem.ToString() +
                          "&qsStartDate=" + lstartdate.Text +
                          "&qsEndDate=" + lenddate.Text +
                          "&qsReason=" + tbreason.Text +
                          "&qsValue=" + total.Text +
                          "&qsSV=" + tbsvemail.Text);

    }
}
```

these are the 2nd page back code.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["ID"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
    if (Session["ID"] != null)
    {
        string id = Session["ID"].ToString();
        sqluser.SelectCommand =
            "SELECT id, name, email " +
            "FROM   profile " +
            "WHERE  id='" + id + "'";

        sqluser.DataBind();

        if (Request.QueryString["qsLeaveCode"] != null &&
            Request.QueryString["&qsLeaveType"] != null &&
            Request.QueryString["&qsStartDate"] != null &&
            Request.QueryString["&qsEndDate"] != null &&
            Request.QueryString["&qsReason"] != null &&
            Request.QueryString["&qsValue"] != null &&
            Request.QueryString["&qsSV"] != null
            )
        {
            lleavetypecode.Text = Request.QueryString["qsLeaveCode"].ToString();
            lleavetype.Text = Request.QueryString["&qsLeaveType"].ToString();
            lstartdate.Text = Request.QueryString["&qsStartDate"].ToString();
            lenddate.Text = Request.QueryString["&qsEndDate"].ToString();
            lleavetype1.Text = Request.QueryString["&qsLeaveType"].ToString();
            lreason.Text = Request.QueryString["&qsReason"].ToString();
            ltotalleavetype.Text = Request.QueryString["&qsValue"].ToString();
            lsvemail.Text = Request.QueryString["&qsSV"].ToString();
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataView dv = (DataView)sqluser.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dv.Table.Rows)
            {
                lname.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
                lemail.Text = dr["email"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

im quite new in c# so forgive me if for my explaining deficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u don't need a `"&"` symbol in if-check and later. QueryStrings are stored without `"&"`

```
   if (Request.QueryString["qsLeaveCode"] != null &&
        Request.QueryString["qsLeaveType"] != null &&
        Request.QueryString["qsStartDate"] != null &&
        Request.QueryString["qsEndDate"] != null &&
        Request.QueryString["qsReason"] != null &&
        Request.QueryString["qsValue"] != null &&
        Request.QueryString["qsSV"] != null
      ){
        lleavetypecode.Text = Request.QueryString["qsLeaveCode"].ToString();
        lleavetype.Text = Request.QueryString["qsLeaveType"].ToString();
        lstartdate.Text = Request.QueryString["qsStartDate"].ToString();
        lenddate.Text = Request.QueryString["qsEndDate"].ToString();
        lleavetype1.Text = Request.QueryString["qsLeaveType"].ToString();
        lreason.Text = Request.QueryString["qsReason"].ToString();
        ltotalleavetype.Text = Request.QueryString["qsValue"].ToString();
        lsvemail.Text = Request.QueryString["qsSV"].ToString();
       }
```

Comment: then how can i change it ?

Comment: what can u change? i posted code for the 2nd page. it should work.

Comment: omg.. half of it worked ! now i have a problem in the calendars code, from the radiobuttonlist, the users leave balance needed to be fetched from database and deducted from the total date selected and displayed in the 2nd page.